# how to inject same instance of one component into several others?

Tags: autofac

Using Autofac, I have the following scenario:

```
public class MainClass
{
     public delegate MainClass Factory();
     public MainClass(Report report, SecondaryClass secClass)
     {
         Report=report;
         SecondaryClass = secClass;
     }
     public Report Report {get; private set;}
     public SecondaryClass SecondaryClass {get; private set;}
}

public class SecondaryClass
{   
     public SecondaryClass(Report report)
     {
         Report=report;
     }
     public Report Report {get; private set;}
}
```

What I would like to achieve is that every time I invoke the Factory() delegate on MainClass, both MainClass and SecondaryClass are injected with the same instance of Report.

Basically

```
public void MyMethod()
{
     var myMainClass = _MainClassFactory.Invoke();
     //How do I do achieve this????
     Debug.Assert (object.ReferenceEquals(myMainClass.Report , myMainClass.SecondaryClass.Report));
}
```

How can I configure MainClass and SecondaryClass?
My current configuration is the following, but it does not seem to achieve what I want.
As a matter of fact, every time I call the Factory method, I get the same instance of Report.

```
        builder.RegisterType<MainClass>().AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<SecondaryClass>().AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<Report>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just have `MainClass` use the `Report` instance from `SecondaryClass`?

Comment: Well, I can definitely do that. But I remember that this was somehow possible with StructureMap, so just wondering if it was possible at all with Autofac

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, it depends.

If you want to express the fact that `MainClass` deliberately requires the same instance of `Report` as the instance of `SecondaryClass` uses, then you should either take the `Report` from the `SecondaryClass` as @adrift has suggested in comments, or use parametrization:

```
public class MainClass
{
 public delegate MainClass Factory();
 public MainClass(Report report, Func<Report, SecondaryClass> secClassFactory)
 {
     Report=report;
     SecondaryClass = secClassFactory(report);
 }
 public Report Report {get; private set;}
 public SecondaryClass SecondaryClass {get; private set;}
}

public class SecondaryClass
{   
 public SecondaryClass(Report report)
 {
     Report=report;
 }
 public Report Report {get; private set;}
}
```

([see autofac wiki for reference](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/RelationshipTypes))
With these approaches you directly show that you require that two objects use the same `Report`.

If your `SecondaryClass` and `MainClass` do not care if they use the same `Report`, and it's just your wish to make them share it, you could use a separate lifetime scope as @adrift has suggested. But beware that if you use other components that depend on `Report`, they'll also get the same instance inside that lifetime scope. It will be kind of a singleton inside the scope.

I do not recomment using lifetime scope if your components do depend on using the same instance. If you did, the requirement would be obfuscated which is bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you resolve `MainType` within a lifetime scope, the same `Report` instance will be used for both `MainClass` and `SecondaryClass`.

So, in your factory method you could do something like this:

```
using (var lifetime = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    return container.Resolve<MainClass>();
}
```